# Averaging event start time from DateTime column

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, average

I'm calculating average start times from events that run late at night and may not start until the next morning.

```
2018-01-09 00:01:38.000
2018-01-09 23:43:22.000
```

currently all I can produce is an average of 11:52:30.0000000

I would like the result to be ~ 23:52

the times averaged will not remain static as this event runs daily and I will have new data daily. I will likely take the most recent 10 records and average them.

Comment: Edit your question and show the code you are currently using.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) an read [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why do think the answer is ~23:52?

Comment: because that is the time between my two sample times. the process starts some time between 23:43 & 00:01

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice to have SQL you're running, but probably you just need to format properly your output, it should be something like this:

```
FORMAT(cast(<your column> as time), N'hh\:mm(24h)')
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will both compute the average across the datetime field and also return the result as a 24hr time notation only.

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(AVG(CAST(<YourDateTimeField_Here> AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) AS TIME) [AvgTime] FROM <YourTableContaining_DateTime>
```

Comment: I've tried this solution but I still get 11:52 am instead of 23:52 pm

Comment: Are you sure the correct answer is not 11:52?  You can certainly add 12h to the timestamp if you'd like.

Comment: yes I'm sure... the process runs at night not during the day (11:52pm and 12:01am are the times I provided), adding 12 hours would not work because other processes averages should be calculated with the same code.

Answer (score 0):

The following will calculate the average time of day, regardless of what day that is.

```
--SAMPLE DATA
create table #tmp_sec_dif
    (
        sample_date_time datetime
    )

insert into #tmp_sec_dif
values ('2018-01-09 00:01:38.000')
    , ('2018-01-09 23:43:22.000')

--ANSWER
declare @avg_sec_dif int

set @avg_sec_dif = 
    (select avg(a.sec_dif) as avg_sec_dif
    from (
        --put the value in terms of seconds away from 00:00:00
        --where 23:59:00 would be -60 and 00:01:00 would be 60
        select iif(
            datepart(hh, sample_date_time) < 12 --is it morning?
            , datediff(s, '00:00:00', cast(sample_date_time as time)) --if morning
            , datediff(s, '00:00:00', cast(sample_date_time as time)) - 86400 --if evening
            ) as sec_dif
        from #tmp_sec_dif
        ) as a
    )

select cast(dateadd(s, @avg_sec_dif, '00:00:00') as time) as avg_time_of_day
```

The output would be an answer of `23:52:30.0000000`

Comment: not in all situations unfortunately if a process runs at 11:00 and 13:00 the average comes out as 00:00, not 12:00

Comment: @KKohls Based on the question and comments on other answers it looks like the process only runs at night, and needs to be able to find an average time based on a 12:00 - 11:59 24 hour clock (instead of 00:00 - 23:59). If that is not the case, do you mind elaborating on the situation and adding the relevant sample data to help further demonstrate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This code allows you to define a date division point. e.g. 18 identifies 6pm. The time calculation would then be based on seconds after 6pm.

```
-- Defines the hour of the day when a new day starts
DECLARE @DayDivision INT = 18

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#StartTimes') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #StartTimes

CREATE TABLE #StartTimes(
    start DATETIME NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #StartTimes
VALUES 
     ('2018-01-09 00:01:38.000')
    ,('2018-01-09 23:43:22.000')

SELECT 
    -- 3. Add the number of seconds to a day starting at the 
    --    day division hour, then extract the time portion
    CAST(DATEADD(SECOND,
        -- 2. Average number of seconds
        AVG(
            -- 1. Get the number of seconds from the day division point (@DayDivision)
            DATEDIFF(SECOND, 
                CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,start) < @DayDivision THEN
                    SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DATEADD(DAY,-1,start)),MONTH(DATEADD(DAY,-1,start)),DAY(DATEADD(DAY,-1,start)),@DayDivision,0)
                ELSE
                    SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(start),MONTH(start),DAY(start),@DayDivision,0)
                END
            ,start)
        )
    ,'01 jan 1900 ' + CAST(@DayDivision AS VARCHAR(2)) + ':00') AS TIME) AS AverageStartTime
FROM #StartTimes
```